# msp432 - Can code written for the TI MSP432 ARM Cortex M4 be ported automatically to other Cortex M4 microcontrollers?

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I will preface  by saying that I am fairly new to programming at the hardware level and that I'm interested in building apps based on the MSP432 microcontroller by Texas Instruments.

I understand that to program this controller, one writes C code, links to the MSPWare library/drivers, and compiles with gcc. Is it possible to take the code written for this controller and deploy to other controllers that are also based on the the Cortex M4 32-bit architecture? What sorts of differences are there between the various implementations of the Cortex M4?

Answer (score 1):

I will say generally not, unlike an x86 pc or a mac, where the masses at least are used to one operating system and that operating system allows for a lot of reverse compatibility, you write a program today on a dell and it works on an acer, and will probably run for another 10 years or more on your daily driver computer or at least many 10 year old or more programs run today, actually in 10 years todays programs probably wont run (on your phone or brain implant).

the cortex-m4 is a processor core, arm doesnt make chips they make processor cores that chip companies buy and surround with chip company stuff.  So instead of saying I can drive a car move me from one car to another and there is a pretty good chance I can drive it, instead this is I am a specific sized tire and move me from one car to another and it is quite likely I dont work.

almost all of the code in the libraries that you are making calls to are for things within the chip, but outside the arm core, the chip vendor specific stuff.  So while that particular chip vendor may make libraries that are close to the same from one of their arm chips to another within a class of chips or within the same production time frame or whatever, that doesnt mean that that code apis or how the peripherals work is in any way portable from one family of chips in that company to another and certainly not from one chip vendor to another.  your ti code is likely not close to what you see on an atmel or nxp or st arm based chip.

Now saying that there are folks trying, the mbed stuff is an attempt to be arduino like where arduino is an attempt to make a high enough set of libraries and port them to specific boards (which are mostly within a family of chips from one vendor). There are some arm based attempts to make arduino libraries such that code developed on a real arduino will compile for these arm based things and just work, but those arm based things are specific boards designed to be ardunio compatable and the libraries are thick and hold all the conversion magic from avr/atmel peripherals to whatever arm based chip was chosen.

mbed is probably closer to it, originally just nxp chips but now some st boards with st chips that are trying to be both arduino compatible and mbed compatible.  not sure how that will work out.

then there are phones of course but that is a lot closer to the windows thing write an iphone app and it will/should work on all the iphones for some period of time, even though those phones all use different arm based chips from different vendors with vastly different peripherals.

This question likely will be closed for being primarily opinion based, since it is not really a black and white fact question.  I suggest you just enjoy the board you bought, make the leds blink and stuff, get used to dealing with a whole new environment compared to operating system stuff, and the very limited resources compared to a laptop/desktop.

If you have a specific porting question or something that is more of a question with a more specific answer then ask it that way.  If you are wanting to play with this but ultimately do X with it (port the code to an stm32f4 for example), will it work.

Now, it is quite likely that if you wanted to create your own abstraction layer, then you could create it such that it works on top of multiple chips/platforms.

Arm has this cmsis thing but I think that is for the debuggers to get common access to the board, you may or may not know or have noticed that the access to the stellaris launchpad now tiva C is a different interface/protocol than the one used now.  The one used now is on the hercules and now msp432 (I hate that, it is in no way shape or form related to the msp430, perhaps this is a pic vs pic32 thing which in no way are related to each other except for being from the same parent company) uses the same XDS100 compatible front end.  The thing that was formerly a board with an attempt to be arduino like easy to use web based environment (arduino is java based not web based, but run anywhere is the idea) and a lot of libraries so you dont have to know as many details, this is mbed, now mbed appears to becoming an rtos or something so kind of like writing for arduino or for android, you might...might...be able to develop on top of that and have it port.  Understand the more layers the thicker the abstraction layer the more resources you need the more power you consume the more the chip cost, etc.  So it is a tradeoff of saving a little bit of software development time vs the price or size or power consumption of the product.  We dont know, nor necessarily need to know, what you are making, that is your business but, there are tradeoffs to making the software "simpler", portable, readable, etc...

Comment: Thank you dwelch for your answer and perspective. It's not completely unexpected that it's not so easy. Polymorphism is a nice ideal, but it's down to the metal I go. Your point about mbed is taken -- the boards are going for double the cost of the msp432.

Comment: Also, the brain implant trademark will be Cortex-InU :)

Comment: lol... actually one/some of the stm32 nucleo boards for example are or were at least around $10 or $11, cheaper than the msp432.  and they have mbed support.  now that may be the cortex-m0 not the m4 but the nucleo boards should be on par price wise.  the original mbed board, yep that is like $50 and although fun and interesting you dont need it just yet.

Comment: I have lots of bare metal mostly arm https://github.com/dwelch67 and a thumb simulator thumbulator if you want to wade around.  basically all bare metal though, no vendor library based code, definitely doesnt port from one board to another.  might be useful or might be completely useless for what you are trying to do or learn.

Comment: I have some msp432 code in the tivac_samples directory.  Just got mine the other day...